# Converting a JApplet to .exe

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a small (Swing) JApplet that runs perfectly in Eclipse: it contains a label, two buttons and a menu, with minimum user interaction (when choosing a menu item, the color of the container changes).
I converted this to a .jar:

- I right clicked the class name (Sw3.java)
- Selected "Export", then "Java", then "JAR file"
- Next, I chose current project name as resource to export, doubled clicked the "Default package" underneath it, selected desired class name from the list of classes in the right (Sw3.java)
- Next, I ticked "Export generated class files and resources", selected the export destination as "JAR file" and placed it in "Documents" under the name "Sw3.jar". I also selected "Compress the contents of the JAR file".
- In the next screen I checked "Export class file with compile errors" and "Export class file with compile warnings"

I heard the right way to obtain an exe file is to convert a .jar into .exe so I used the "Launch4j" application with the .jar obtained previously:

- In the "Basic" panel: specified OUTPUT FILE: C:\Users\jerry\Documents\Sw3.exe and the JAR file: C:\Users\jerry\Documents\Sw3.jar.
- Process priority NORMAL
- Header type: GUI
- MIN JRE Version: 1.0.0
- I pressed the "wheel" and chose Project.xml and got a succesful confirmation message.

I have JRE installed, so the .exe should work, but it doesn't work. What did I do wrong? I would start by investigating if the .JAR was correctly obtained, is that a good approach and how would I check that? Thank you!

PS: Upon being advised to use JFrame instead of JApplet, I did that and still nothing happens when I double click the .exe in order to open it. This makes me suspect there is something wrong in the steps I described.

Comment: Why have you made a JApplet instead of a simple JFrame? Applets are special beasts, and while they can be run on the desktop in some case, they are more made to be put on a Web page (and it becomes out of fashion, apparently).

Comment: Thank you PhiLho, I used JApplet because I'm new, practising Swing and and more comfortable with that rather than JFrame. However, I added a JFrame as advised by martijno below and yourself and I still have the same issue.

Comment: I was thinking of using a pure JFrame. I just don't know if Launch4j can handle a JApplet (a Google search returns zero occurrence, which is rare!). You can try and launch the exe from the command line with the `--l4j-debug` option, maybe you will get some relevant error message.

Comment: Thanks PhiLo, I followed that advice, chose the second example from this link and just added a few extra lines and components (e.g. a label) http://jsong.ba.ttu.edu/ISQS2341/Fall05/Lecture08_Example.pdf. This didn't work so I tried again with a more complex JFrame example, the MyFrame example from the same link. Both work perfectly when I run them from Eclipse, so there must be something wrong in the steps I presented in the original question above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a main method to your applet to put it inside a `JFrame`:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  JApplet applet = new Sw3();
  frame.getContentPane().add(applet);
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
  applet.init();
  applet.start();
}
```

In the Eclipse JAR exportation dialog, after the "JAR Packaging Options" screen (the one with "Export class files with error and/or warnings" that you mention above), click **next** (and not *finish*). Choose "Generate manifest file" and enter the fully qualified (i.e. including package) class name of your main class:

[image: Generate manifest with Main-class attribute from Eclipse JAR export]

Comment: Thank you Martijno, I did add the main method with JApplet applet = new Sw3(); to accomodate to my situation and went through all the steps again as presented in my initial question; however I still see no change, unf. If I double click the .exe to open it nothing happens.

Comment: Are you specifying the class that contains the main method (your applet class, probably) in the jar's manifest somewhere?

Comment: I think I do it on the 3rd step, but am not sure if this is what you refer to: [I chose current project name as resource to export, doubled clicked the "Default package" underneath it, selected desired **class name** (the JFrame class) from the list of classes in the right.] In the last step of the JAR export I also saw "Specify the manifest" selected by default and left it as such. "Use existing manifest from workspace" is the second option there. Maybe the JAR is not generated correctly.

Comment: Editing my answer... hang on.

Comment: Oh my, it worked, I have to remember this step from now on and add it to the procedure, thank you so much, I'm really happy now! You are fabulous!